# How to disable a period after double-space in Mac OS Ventura?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, ventura

I am on Ventura 13.0.1 and cannot seem to find a setting to disable Mac automatically entering a period after a double-space. In past versions of Mac OS, there was a setting under Preferences -> Keyboard -> Text (see below), but that setting no longer exists. I have searched through the new settings screen (also see below), but for the life of me I can't find anything that helps.

Old (pre-Ventura) keyboard setting screen:

[image]

New (Ventura) keyboard setting screen:

[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you click on "Edit..." under Text Input, you'll see the options there.

[image]

Comment: You're a lifesaver!

Comment: Thanks! This is _also_ where you turn off "smart" quotes and can set the single and double quotes to regular ascii quote marks. Using `“…”` in place of `"…"` in programming causes your compile to fail. Programming languages use _straight_ quotes.

Comment: @StephenP True, though decent IDEs and text editors usually have their own settings or don't use Smart Quotes, e.g. BBEdit, CodeRunner, Xcode, IDLE, etc.

Comment: @StephenP I have smart quotes enabled but I've never had any issues with places expecting straight quotes. I believe it only affects some selected Apple apps (but definitely not XCode), but third party apps have their own control. I'm curious, where did you experience smart quotes interfering with programming source code?

Comment: @ADTC sorry I don't remember which environment it was in. I bounce around depending on which project I'm working on, so I don't remember how I got the smart quotes in the file ... but the result of compiling was `error: illegal character: '\u201d'`